# Change value of input field on another field's blur event in Strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I've been struggling with the docs of strapi for this.

There's a collection of articles. When creating an article, there are 2 fields i.e Start Date and End Date. Now when a value of Start Date changes and user is done selecting an event, I want to update the value of End Date 6 months from that.

Ofcourse the calculations of value are not a problem but I'm unable to find anything to update the value on blur event.

Right now, I'm using **beforeCreate** and **beforeUpdate** lifecycle hooks but all these hooks mentioned in strapi doc run when a user clicks **Save** button.

This might solve the case but this is not an idea scenario for a user coming from Wordpress or any other custom CMS where this is easily doable

Answer (score 2):

Strapi is not providing any blur events  for now . We have Posted Comments on the strapi forum untill then only way to fix this is by using life cycle events provided by strapi. Refer this link https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#lifecycle-hooks

1. Get Date and Time in Separate Fields .
2. Merge those values when clicking on save button .

https://forum.strapi.io/t/change-value-of-input-field-on-another-fields-blur-event-in-strapi/19829

Comment: Well, that sucks. Such basic functionality should be available.